# Large table random select with some peculiarity

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with 800k rows and I need to select 20 random rows that not are in other 2 tables (tickets already purchased).

I already tried a SQL with NOT IN syntax, but it's still (sometimes 1s in development machine).

Actual SQL:

```
SELECT id, description 
FROM ticket
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id 
                  FROM cart_item 
                  WHERE DATE(added) = CURDATE() ) 
  AND id NOT IN ( SELECT id 
                  FROM valid_ticket )
  AND id BETWEEN 1 AND 200000
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

I need some faster. Because grabbing all table and select 20 rand rows is very slow. That function is executed is all pages of a website and I'm thinking how to optimize and cache that query.

Thanks all for support

Comment: 1) Rewrite `NOT IN` to `LEFT JOIN`. 2) Replace `DATE(added) = CURDATE()` with `added >= CURDATE() AND added < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` 3)How many records (approximately) does the subqueries selects?

Comment: And, because you use more than one table, add table alias to EACH field in a query.

Comment: Hi @Akina, thanks. the num of records it's variable, because it's a table of carts and sales. But we can be talking in something like 10k carts per day and 50k valid tickets (per week - where is missing in this query).

Comment: You could add the AND id BETWEEN 1 AND 200000 to both of the subqueries.

Comment: Guys, the users add items in cart_item and valid_ticket based on the results of this query. So there are only rows between 1 and 200k on that 2 related tables.

Answer (score 0):

First, `ORDER BY RAND()` will collect all the rows, tack on `RAND()`, sort, and then start work.

Actually, it is not that bad, since you have filtering.  But it may not help a lot.

```
AND id BETWEEN 1 AND 200000
```

limits the work to 200K instead of 800K.

The other filters involve what *might* be a terribly inefficient construct:  `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`.  It *may* be turned into a different construct.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT  ...`

```
DATE(added) = CURDATE()
```

Assuming `added` is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, and there are not values in the future, then change to

```
added >= CURDATE()
```

and have `INDEX(added, id)`.

After I see the `EXPLAIN`, I may suggest using `EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`.